# Figaro Gem - Declare a variable for 2 environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, environment-variables

I am using FIGARO with the application.yml file.

I would like to declare a variable for both environment, for exemple let's say:

```
development:
  COUCHBASE_URL: couch-1.io
test:
  COUCHBASE_URL: couch-1.io
production:
  COUCHBASE_URL: couch-2.io
```

how could I do something like that:

```
development, test:
  COUCHBASE_URL: couch-1.io
```

Do you know the correct way to do it ?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use shared values:

```
defaults: &defaults
  COUCHBASE_URL: 'couch-1.io'

development:
  <<: *defaults
test:
  <<: *defaults
```

Now both environments would share the same variables defined under `defaults`